# Android 6.0 USB Mass Storage

Tags: android, android-ndk, usb-mass-storage

USB mass storage is now officially supported by Android, exclusively through the Storage Access Framework.  It does not seem to mount the storage in a typical sense, as far as I can tell the only way to access the data is through the Document API and `ContentResolver`.

1) Is there no longer a simple `File` way to access the storage after going through the SAF?

2) If not, what's the best way to interact with 'files' on USB storage in NDK if we don't have access to paths.

Comment: "Is there no longer a simple File way to access the storage after going through the SAF?" -- AFAIK, USB Mass Storage is treated no differently than other forms of [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). In which case, `getExternalFilesDirs()` and kin (note the plural) may return `File` locations on removable storage that your app can read from and write to. Beyond that, you do not have direct access.

Comment: Unless the javadoc has not been updated:

`External storage devices returned here are considered a permanent part of the device, including both emulated external storage and physical media slots, such as SD cards in a battery compartment. The returned paths do not include transient devices, such as USB flash drives.`

Comment: Well, Android has no way on its own to tell whether an SD card slot is in a battery compartment or not, so I would take that bit of documentation with a grain of salt. That being said, if `getExternalFilesDirs()` and kin do not work, then you have no access to the USB flash drive at all, except perhaps through the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: Confirmed `getExternalFilesDirs()` only returns the hardware mounted storage.  It's amazing a change of this magnitude garnered a single sentence in the release notes.  4.4, 5.0, 6.0.  I see where they wanted to go with files, but I don't think they possibly could have executed this any worse.  Constant major rewrites over the course of two years.

Comment: 'if getExternalFilesDirs() and kin do not work, then you have no access to the USB flash drive at all, '. Well that is no reason as i never saw a usb flash drive mentioned there where it was always accessable by /mnt or /storage. But indeed i can confirm that it is not accessable with a File explorer on 6.0

Comment: It is `not mounted`.  It `is` accessible.  It just requires a LOT more work than it used to.  Using the SAF you can get something along the lines of:

`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/0000-0000%3A/document/0000-0000%3ADCIM%2F100EOS5D%2FIMG_0081.CR2`

which can be converted into a stream with ContentResolver successfully.  I'm willing to bet it's half the speed and I know it's literally hundreds of times the effort, but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of flaws in the implementation of `DocumentFile`, primarily as it relates to "tree" vs "document" uris and the fact that you [cannot store a "tree" uri due to a huge bug in the factory](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200941), but also in the [lack of 'parent' functionality](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199562), so I wrote a useful one, cleverly named `UsefulDocumentFile`

https://github.com/rcketscientist/DocumentActivity/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/anthonymandra/framework/UsefulDocumentFile.java

`UsefulDocumentFile` can stand on it's own, but the overall project is an attempt to patch the life-cycle snafu Google created with SAF (If you request write permission you interrupt the pending write action to open SAF which is awful HMI).