# Get external storage path for USB-flash with Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, usb, android-external-storage

Using Android 6.0.1 (API23) on a Nexus 5X,

The different Android versions and how to access an external storage (i.e. USB-Stick in my case) can be very confusing. From what I understood, you need to give permissions in your manifest, as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

After that you should be able to access external storage..

Here is my approach on how to get the external-storage path, using "getExternalFilesDirs()" method. But it turns out, only the internal SD card is recognized (i.e. first array-element returned by the method).

From what I read, there should be more array-elements returned with the "getExternalFilesDirs()"-method if more external memory devices are connected to the phone. But in my case, none of them is available.

Here is my code :

```
    String strInfo = "";
    File folders[] = getExternalFilesDirs(null);
    // File folders[] = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this,null);
    strInfo += "\ngetExternalFilesDirs(null):\n";
    for(File f : folders){
        strInfo += f.getAbsolutePath() + "\n";
    }
    if (folders.length > 1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "nr of folders = " + folders.length + "/ info = " + strInfo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        File myFile = new File(folders[1], "testfile.txt");
    } else {

    // !!!!!!!!!!!!! Keep ending up in this case, even tough a USB-stick is
    // connected to the phone (...also tried with a second SD-card
    // connected...but same thing, keeeping up ending here... 
    // any idea WHY ???????????????

        Toast.makeText(this, "No external storage device found / info = " + strInfo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Eventually, I would like to create files and folders on an externally connected USB-stick. Can anybody tell me a reliable method on how to create new files and folders on an USB-stick connected to an Android-6.0.1 phone ??
I appreciate it.

Comment: Which device? In 6.0 ..FilesDirs() will normalle contain the path. Does it mention a removable micro SD card used as portable?

Comment: `a reliable method on how to create new files and folders on an USB-stick`. There is nothing different with creating files there. I thougth your problem was finding the path to the usb drive.

Comment: "From what I understood, you need to give permissions in your manifest, as follows" -- no. Those are not relevant for [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). "there should be more array-elements returned with the "getExternalFilesDirs()"" -- are you sure that the device is recognizing your USB stick? It should appear in "Storage & USB" in Settings, and there should be a `Notification` allowing you to explore or eject the volume.

Comment: `After that you should be able to access external storage.`. No. On 6.0 you should ask for runtime permissions. Now did you? Or did you go to the Settings for your app to put them on manually?

Comment: Thanks for the many answers. Here my reply to hopefully most of your questions:

Comment: @greenapps: Device=Nexus-5X (it has an SDcard inside that is recognized as the first "external storage").But I do not want to write on there, I want to write files and folders on an external USB-stick. And for that I need its path...

Comment: @CommonsWare: Ok, I will leave out the manifest-permissions then.... And yes, the USB-stick is recognized in Settings (under Storage & USB) and yes if I load permissions as follows, I also get the notification asking to "Allow MyApp to access photos, media, and files on my device". The permission I cause with the following code (see next reply)

Comment: @ CommonsWare: here my code:     private void loadPermissions(String perm,int requestCode) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, perm)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{perm}, requestCode);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @greenapps: I tried both (i.e. ask for runtime permission with reply just given / and also under Settings to put them on manually...)

Comment: Or how do you exactly ask for runtime permissions on 6.0 ??

Comment: `I want to write files and folders on an external USB-stick. And for that I need its path`. Why are you repeating yourself? Of course i had understood that.

Comment: `I tried......to put them on manually...`. Well did you succeede?

Comment: @greenapps: Yes I did succeed to put them on manually and also from code. But I guess, my real question behind all this is how to write files and folders on to a USB-stick from code ? (my guess was to get the path first and then use some filestream-code to write files...). Am I right on this ? Or do you have an alternative way on how to write files and folders on to a USB-stick ??

Comment: The way to write to it is the same as always. If you have the path you can go. I thought your problem was to get the path to the app specific directory as only there you can write. If you know the path then for a test put it in hardcoded and go on.

Comment: No, I do not have the path. From my initial question you can see how I tried to get the path (i.e. using getExternalFilesDirs()) - but as it turns out, this does give me back "null" instead of the desired path to the USB-stick.

Comment: You can find the path with any file explorer app on your device i think.

Comment: Is there anything else needed (except the permission giving, either manually or from code ?). Is my code-permission in the above reply correct ? What else is missing here ?

Comment: Did we comment on something missing? We only commented that you have to find out the path.

Comment: I tried ESFileExplorer to exactly do that. But with that I only see "/1002/UsbStorage" which can't be the full path or is it ?

Comment: How can I test if this (or any) is the correct path for my externally connected USB-stick? Any sample-code on this ?

Comment: Indeed. That is not a normal absolute path. Look under /storage you might find something like /storage/A1B2-2014.

Comment: You don't have arbitrary access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). You will not have read/write access to that location. `getExternalFilesDirs()` and kin (e.g., `getExternalCacheDirs()`) should work. Contact your device manufacturer to determine why their Android build is broken. Beyond that, you can try `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, and kin as part of [the Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html).

Comment: under /storage I find: two folders 1.emulated / 2. self (both are empty). ...i.e. having the USB-stick connected of course...

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thank you - I'll have a look at that..

Comment: So ES File Explorer can show you the contents of the usb drive? Try to find absolute path of some files to find out the absolute path of the drive. Or maybe Storage Access Framework is used.

Comment: How can I find out if Storage Access Framework is used (...and what is it exactly anyway ;))

Comment: I connect another USB-adapter having an SD-card inside and now EsFileExplorer shows "/storage/6236-6330"  But this is not a directory. How can I write a file on there now ?

Comment: Any USB-Stick that I connect does not show anything under /storage  (the USB-to-SDcard-adapter shows /storage/6236-6330 as mentioned). Question is, why do the USB-sticks not show anything in EsFileExplorer (settings->Permissions->Storage-> set manually)

Comment: Finally found the entire path: usb://1002/myStick/ (...but is this useful here ?) I am more and more lost...

Comment: Again, you mentioned: `you might find something like /storage/A1B2-2014`  I found /storage/F49E-14F2 (or /storage/A6236-6330 for the other USB-stick). But what can I do now with that ? How do I write a file or folder on there now ? Any help appreciated

Comment: What is the problem? You have a path. Then you can try to create directories and files on it as usual.You did all those things before i think.

Comment: yes, but..I can try again...

Comment: Just one more question: it seems to me that /storage/A1B2-2014 is not a folder (or is it ?). How do I create a File myFile = ??? (pointing to the correct path ? Maybe I am doing something wrong there...

Comment: String path ="/storage/A1B2-2014/myfolder"; File subdir = new File (path); if (!subdir.exists()) if (!subdir.mkdirs()) { toast sorry could not make directory; return;}

Comment: And why do you think its not a folder? You can browse in it with your file explorer isnt it?

Comment: I think it is not a folder since in ESFileExplorer (or in TotalCommander) I cannot browse in it. Also your above code ends up in `could not make directory` ... I really think, it is still not the right path. Also, the question remains why `File folders[] = getExternalFilesDirs(null);` does only give one folder (i.e. the folder to the SDcard built into my Nexus5X) but no other array-folder. Supposedly it should give back an array with ALL external storages (including USB-sticks or more external SDcards...). But it does not. Why ? (I am using Android 6.0.1 and API 23)

Answer (score 1):

To close this off: USB-sticks do not seem to work as SECONDARY STORAGE (= external storage) for Android-mobile phones, unfortunately.

I just found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693645/android-6-0-usb-mass-storage), saying:

```
External storage devices returned here are considered a permanent part
of the device, including both emulated external storage and physical
media slots, such as SD cards in a battery compartment. The returned
paths do not include transient devices, such as USB flash drives.
```

And similar, the [official Android documentation about getExternalFilesDirs()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String)) sais:

```
The returned paths do not include transient devices, such as USB flash drives 
connected to handheld devices.
```

If anybody knows a C-Type USB-stick that does fulfill the requirements of a SECONDARY STORAGE, please let me know ! The same, if anybody knows USB-C-type SDcard-Adapters that work as SECONDARY STORAGE, please let me know...

Too bad, I am not able to write files & folders from my java android app to an external USB-stick :(